# setFirstResult and setMaxResults doesnt work as expected

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite, dialect

I have a problem with paging in my application. I wanna use setFirstResult and setMaxResults methods, but it gave me wrong output:

(My database: SQLite)

Example:

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    int page = 0;
    int maxRows = 20;

    while (page < 5) {

        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Book.class);
        criteria.setFirstResult(page * maxRows).setMaxResults(maxRows);
        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("id"));
        List<Book> list = criteria.list();

        System.out.println("FirstRow: " + page * maxRows + " - RowsLimit: " + maxRows);
        for (Book b : list) {
            System.out.println(b.getId());
        }
        page++;
    }
    session.close();
```

The output gave me:

```
FirstRow: 0 - RowsLimit: 20
1
.
.
.
20
FirstRow: 20 - RowsLimit: 20
21
.
.
.
40
FirstRow: 40 - RowsLimit: 20
21
.
.
.
40
FirstRow: 60 - RowsLimit: 20
21
.
.
.
40
```

I have no idea why only first two "pages" are working correctly and after them it gave me the same range of rows.

Thx for any advice

Comment: Do you know how to configure Hibernate to print out the SQL it is generating?

Comment: Do you mean "show_sql", "format_sql" and "use_sql_comments" property in hibernate.cfg.xml ??

Comment: Yes. Just set `show_sql` and `format_sql` to `true`.

Comment: Interesting, it printed only sub-select query of Author (it is in (Author) many to one (Book) relation) 
`Hibernate: 
    select
        this_.id as id0_0_,
        this_.firstName as firstName0_0_,
        this_.lastName as lastName0_0_ 
    from
        Author this_ 
    order by
        this_.id asc limit ? offset ?
FirstRow: 20 - RowsLimit: 20`

Comment: Ok maybe there is another way to make paging. Something like scrollable but i need to keep high performance. Table has 15 000 rows. ideas ?

Comment: No I think you're close, but maybe something is off in your configuration of `Author` and `Book` classes. Also, `show_sql` causes all sql to get printed -- maybe you are not seeing the whole log?

Comment: Maybe i have found my problem solution here:

http://shagy0101.blogspot.cz/2012/03/sqlite-jpa-hibernate-pagination.html

I'll send you feedback after testing.

Comment: Thx david. The solution I've found is below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok here is the solution.

http://shagy0101.blogspot.cz/2012/03/sqlite-jpa-hibernate-pagination.html

Problem was in SQLite Dialect. Just add to your SQLiteDialect this method:

```
 @Override
 public boolean bindLimitParametersInReverseOrder(){
     return true;
 }
```